# aggregate function is not intuitive

Tags: r, aggregate

Like the following source code about aggregation function, I can't understand why we have to use list function() in here. Rather than I want to replace this with using one column that is needs to be grouped by. And I don't know why we use the same dataset like 'train[Sales != 0]' twice? What if I use other dataset as a second dataset param? I think it will make change to be fairly high possible mistake.

```
aggregate(train[Sales != 0]$Sales, 
               by = list(train[Sales != 0]$Store), mean)
```

Maybe one who can say this is wrong use case. But I also saw this source code in R Documentation

```
## Compute the averages for the variables in 'state.x77', grouped
## according to the region (Northeast, South, North Central, West) that
## each state belongs to.
aggregate(state.x77, list(Region = state.region), mean)
```

Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: I think your code could be wrong. If `train` is a matrix or data.frame this command `train[Sales != 0]` gives you already an error (`undefined columns selected`). Nevertheless, you can do that `aggregate(Sales ~ Store, data = train[Sales != 0, ], mean)` to avoid the `list()`function. `state.x77` is a dataset already attached, therefore you can use it like in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you don't like the syntax of the aggregate function, you could take a look at the `dplyr` package. Its syntax might be a bit easier for you.

To answer your questions:

1. The second argument is just expected to be a list, so you can add multiple variables.
2. You have to use `train[Sales != 0]` two times, because otherwise the first and the `by` argument look at different indices. You could also make a subset first:

Base R-code:

```
trainSales <- train[Sales != 0]  
aggregate( trainSales$Sales, by = list(trainSales$Store), mean )
```

With `dplyr` you could do something like this:

```
train %>%
    filter( Sales != 0) %>%
    group_by( Store ) %>%
    summarise_each( funs(mean) )
```

You see I use `summarise_each` because it condenses the dataset to one row, but you could off course also do something that leaves all the rows intact (in that case, use `do`).

Comment: `aggregate` has a nice formula method with more convenient syntax.

Comment: @Jasper Thanks. But I think this function would be better if it takes dataset, a column to be aggregated, a column to be referenced t to group by and aggregation function.

Comment: @verystrongjoe I added an example with `dplyr` as well, maybe that's more intuitive? Check out [Introduction to dplyr](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) if you want to learn more about its syntax. It's really handy when you get the hang of it.